.Net 8 Blazor - Missing CSS file after publish
I'm starting a new .Net 8 Blazor application.
When I run the dotnet publish -c Release command and start the published application I get a 404 error for my css file. This doesn't happen when I developing (using the dotnet watch or dotnet run).
Here you can see it works on the dotnet run command
This is the error I am running into
Any help would be appreciated!
I've tried starting a new application in the hopes that I accidentally passed some arguments wrong.
edit:
Here are the steps to reproduce the error:

in your terminal run dotnet new blazor -o ./Blazor.Host
run cd ./Blazor.Host
rundotnet publish
run dotnet path/to/app/Blazor.Host.dll

It doesn't look like any of the static files are getting served

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

And post code and errors as text, so that it can be found.

I'm running into the error without changing any of the default files that come with the template. I hope my edited original post can help you reproduce the error

I also reproduce issue in .net8 when adding path when using dotnet dll command. And it has the StaticFileMiddleware warning like below.

You could try replace the staticFiles middleware like below to solve the problem
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "wwwroot")),
    RequestPath = ""
});

Additionally, this problem has been disappeared in .Net9 template which uses app.MapStaticAssets();
